# In Bash, how do I add a string after each line in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

How do I add a string after each line in a file using bash? Can it be done using the sed command, if so how?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

If your `sed` allows in place editing via the `-i` parameter:

```
sed -e 's/$/string after each line/' -i filename
```

If not, you have to make a temporary file:

```
typeset TMP_FILE=$( mktemp )

touch "${TMP_FILE}"
cp -p filename "${TMP_FILE}"
sed -e 's/$/string after each line/' "${TMP_FILE}" > filename
```

Comment: Why do you `touch` the temporary file? And I would make the `sed` command conditional on the success of the `cp` or the original could be lost.

Comment: I touched the file to quickly reserve the temporary name.  This may not be needed.  I think you are right about making the sed command conditional on the success of the cp.  Why not edit the code to make that fix.  I won't mind a bit!

Yours,
Tom

Comment: What about adding a string *before* a line?

Comment: @Oxwivi: `sed -e 's/^/string after each line/' -i filename`  
  
$ means end-of-line. ^ means beginning of line.

Comment: If I'm piping into sed, `sed 's/^/string after each line/'` does what I'd expect (prepends to each line) but `sed 's/^/string after each line/'` does not (it replaces the whole line with my append string). What gives? Any ideas @TomDeGisi ?

Comment: @CleberGoncalves You're right! In reviewing this old comment, I believe what was happening was that prepending via `sed 's/^/string before each line/'` works, but that appending with `sed 's/$/string after each line/'` was not. Possible dos2unix issue?

Comment: @philadams http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909043/how-to-add-a-string-from-variables-to-each-line-in-a-file-in-bash

Comment: Could you please explain what the $ sign does in your answer? Answers are more helpful if you understand what is happening.

Comment: `string after each line` can't be a var, as in `$stringaftereachline`. it appends `$stringaftereachline` to each line

Comment: @shuhalo According to gnu sed documentation `$ also acts as a special character only at the end of the regular expression`. So `$` regexp grabs the end of each line and `s/$/appendix/` substitues the end of a line with a given string. This is my understanding.

Comment: No need for `-e <expression> -i <file>`, `-i` implies applying an expression on the file, so `-i <expression> <file>` suffices.

Answer (score 33):

I prefer `echo`. using pure bash:

```
cat file | while read line; do echo ${line}$string; done
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, it can be used with the output of `ls` (or anything that produces multiline output).

Comment: first add value to string variable, like string=0

Comment: I m not sure why, but using this, the $string appears before ${line}

Comment: i found out why. fellas, there is a carriage return \r which you need to take care fo

Answer (score 26):

I prefer using `awk`.
If there is only one column, use `$0`, else replace it with the last column.

One way,

```
awk '{print $0, "string to append after each line"}' file > new_file
```

or this,

```
awk '$0=$0"string to append after each line"' file > new_file
```

Comment: Also, to append line numbers (as was in my case), one can use `NR` variable: `awk '{print $0, NR}'`

Comment: @optimus I've tried your method, but getting an extra space bw them, any idea on how to remove them?

Comment: @AdilSaju `sed 's/ //g'` this worked for my requirement, but it will remove space in every line, thats what option `g` for and everywhere in a line.

Comment: @AdilSaju please add details. Better to ask a new question.

Comment: @AdilSaju awk Remove `, ` like `{print $0"string to append after each line"}`.

Answer (score 11):

If you have it, the [lam](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/lam/) (laminate) utility can do it, for example:

```
$ lam filename -s "string after each line"
```

Answer (score 8):

1. Pure *POSIX shell* and [`sponge`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

   ```
   suffix=foobar
   while read l ; do printf '%s\n' "$l" "${suffix}" ; done < file | 
   sponge file
   ```
2. `xargs` and `printf`:

   ```
   suffix=foobar
   xargs -L 1 printf "%s${suffix}\n" < file | sponge file
   ```
3. Using `join`:

   ```
   suffix=foobar
   join file file -e "${suffix}" -o 1.1,2.99999 | sponge file
   ```
4. Shell tools using `paste`, `yes`, `head`
   & `wc`:

   ```
   suffix=foobar
   paste file <(yes "${suffix}" | head -$(wc -l < file) ) | sponge file
   ```

   Note that `paste` inserts a *Tab* char before `$suffix`.

Of course `sponge` can be replaced with a temp file, afterwards `mv`'d over the original filename, as with some other answers...

Comment: None of these are preferable to `sed`, unless resources are very limited.

Comment: I like the non-sed solution. `sed` is not needed for such a simple job.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to add on using the echo command to add a string at the end of each line in a file:

```
cat input-file | while read line; do echo ${line}"string to add" >> output-file; done
```

Adding *>>* directs the changes we've made to the output file.

Comment: I think this has a spurious $ (the black one).

Comment: @ndtreviv, that's a good catch. I'll edit it out. Thank YOU!

Comment: UUOC (useless use of cat): You can just do `< input-file while read line; do ... ; done` (or if you prefer `while read line; do ... ; done < input-file`)