# Export MongoDB data and appending values to each row

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have a MongoDB collection that needs to be exported on a scheduled basis on an Ubuntu Server. However I want to add a year and month to the end of each row of data during the export as a sort of time stamp. This is so that a second BI tool can import the data from CSV format with the month and year on each record as an effective transaction date. This would mean that the following months import would have that months timestamp.

I understand how to use the mongoexport tool to get the data out to the CSV format, but appending the month and year to each row is the gap here.

Comment: One idea I had was to run a JSON update to the data to insert the values prior to the export. This would then be part of the schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can, not directly with `mongoexport`. Nothing stops you from processing the output, though, and append `"[YYYY]","[MM]"` at the end of each line.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869669/in-bash-how-do-i-add-a-string-after-each-line-in-a-file) seems to be one option for appending a known string to each line in a text file, but bash being bash, I'm sure there's thousands of way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Nicolas. Using a text append in that way was one of the options I was considering, but was hoping to get it done as part of the export. I suspect you are right though and this can't be done via the export function.

Comment: Another idea is, if you're not interested on a per-tuple date, why not encode the date information in the file name and have your import script read it there? It's probably a good idea to timestamp your various export files anyway (`export_2013_09.csv`, `export_2013_10.csv`…)

Comment: I had suggested that to the other developer, however in the BI tool, they would prefer to have a fixed name for locating the correct file. Also the tool doesn't play nicely in extracting values from the filename itself.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. Resolved the issue for me thanks @Nicolas. Just need to work out how to insert the actual year and month now. :)