# Trying to add a char to the end of each line in a given file, how is it done?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which looks like that:

```
sudo apt-get install rar
sudo apt-get install gimp
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```

I want to somehow add "-y" in the end of each line, how is it done?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Bash, how do I add a string after each line in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869669/in-bash-how-do-i-add-a-string-after-each-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i 's:$: -y:' YOURFILE
```

Will do it for you.

1. `-i` does the modification "in place", so no new file created (actully there's a tmp file)
2. `s` substitute
3. `:`delimiter
4. `$` end of line
5. see the 3. point
6. `-y` replacement

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to add `-y` (change it as you deem appropriate) at the end of each line, you can use `sed` by saying

```
$ cat file
sudo apt-get install rar
sudo apt-get install gimp
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```

```
$ sed 's/$/ -y/' file
sudo apt-get install rar -y
sudo apt-get install gimp -y
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool -y
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool -y
sudo apt-get install pidgin -y
```

This prints on standard out. If you wish to make in-place changes inside the file, you can use `-i` option of `sed` by saying

```
sed -i 's/$/ -y/' file
```

or redirect the output to another file by doing

```
sed 's/$/ -y/' file > newfile
```

Comment: That would not work for the `apt-get` properly... Although I see the specification was asking for that :-)

Comment: @jaypal it has to be `sudo apt-get install rar -y`. So that the command will work. `-y` is a special flag in `apt-get` which means `assume-yes`

Comment: @jaypal Most probably if the user executes the output, `apt-get` will not find those packages. I do thinkk that the user wants to add the `-y` as a parameter to the `apt-get` command instead of modifying the to be installed package name (still, he specified the way you had solved it... but a quick check in the `apt-get` DB could show that there are no packages with names like that...)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Have made the change to add a space. I don't have Ubuntu so not familiar with `apt-get`.

Comment: it's not your fault. OP failed to mention what he wants correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are `vi` mode you can try

```
:%s/$/text_to_be_added/g and press "Enter"
```

If you are `bash` mode you can try

```
sed 's/$/text_to_be_added/g' filename
```

Comment: The `g` is useless in this case.