# How to add a string from variables to each line in a file in BASH

Tags: linux, bash

I have this one :

```
sed -e 's/$/string after each line/' -i filename
```

but i want instead of "string after each line"

have a string from the following result:

```
cat filename2 | tr '\n' ' '
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can just save this string in a variable like so:

```
$ myvar=`cat filename2 | tr '\n' ' '`; sed -e "s/$/ $myvar/" -i filename
```

Basically, you store the value of the command inside `myvar`.
Then, you run `sed` and provide the contents of `$myvar` as a string for the `s` (substitute) command.