# Paste a repeating word as a column in Terminal

Tags: shell, terminal

I have a tab delimited txt file with two columns of data, ex:

```
PopA 1
PopB 2
PopC 3
PopD 4
```

I would like to paste a third column for the entire file, with each line being the same, 'EcoRI', thus:

```
PopA 1 EcoRI
PopB 2 EcoRI
PopC 3 EcoRI
PopD 4 EcoRI
```

What is a convenient way to do this simple process in Terminal??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Bash, how do I add a string after each line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869669/in-bash-how-do-i-add-a-string-after-each-line-in-a-file)

Comment: `sed -i.bk 's/$/\tEcoRI/' file.txt`

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, that helped, I was struggling with the different options of `sed`

Comment: @SamuelKirschner that did the trick...what does the `-i.bk` specifically refer to. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `man sed`. The `-i.bk` created a backup file `file.txt.bk`. `-iABC` would create `file.txtABC` as backup. Only `-i` creates no backup. No `-i` at all, does not modify the file, just outputs the result.

Comment: See this Q&A for in-place specifics with sed in different versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-file-in-place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this could help:

```
awk '{print $0 "\tEcoRI"}' file.txt
```

This will append at the end of each line a tab `\t` and your text `EcoRI`

If you would like to save the output you could use:

```
awk '{print $0 "\tEcoRI"}' file.txt > file2.txt
```

Comment: thanks, though it appeared to only make a single space instead of a tab between the 2nd and 3rd column...not sure if this would functionally make a difference

Comment: The `\t` should add a tab before the text, in any case, after saving the file `file.txt > fiel2.txt` you could use `cat -t file2.txt`  the `-t` in cat will help to display not-printing characters so could help to distinguish tabs vs spaces