# insert sting before and behind using sed

Tags: sed

my protoype `sed -e 'stringStart; s/$/stringEnd/' -i ./tabs.txt`

adds `stringEnd` behind each line as wanted

but ignores `stringStart`

its my first time using sed, so i read here:

- https://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/sedoneliner.htm?print=246
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869736/2891692

## source tabs.txt

```
&clipboard
Pana
```

## expected result tabs.txt

```
stringStart&clipboardstringEnd
stringStartPanastringEnd
```

## result with this prototype tabs.txt

```
&clipboardstringEnd
PanastringEnd
```

Comment: Use: `sed -i 's/.*/stringStart&stringEnd/' tabs.txt`

Comment: Or `sed -i 's/^/stringStart/;s/$/stringEnd/' tabs.txt`

Comment: your both solutions works really good.