# substitution into address space of 's' (sed command) from file with regex

Tags: linux, bash, sed

How to perform a substitution like this:

```bash
sed -nE "/file_with_set_of_regexes/ s/$/some_string/p" file_with_data_to_check > file_with_processed_data
```

`file_with_set_of_regexes` contains one regex per line

I tried this

```bash
for i in `cat ./file_regex`; do
  sed -En '/`echo "$i"`/ s/$/some_string/p' file_with_data
done
```

or

```bash
sed -En -e '/`while read -r ch; do a+=$ch; done <file_regex; echo "$i"`/ s/$/some_string/p' file_with_data
```

Unfortunately none of my attempts worked. I got nothing, not even errors.

P.S.

```bash
i="$(<file_regex)"
sed -nE -e "/$i/ s/\$/some_string/p" file_with_data
```

The above code works fine when 'file_regex' contains a single line. If this file contains more than one line I have error:  unterminated address regex

Part of *'file_with_data'*

```
Acetylsalicylic acid
Acetylsalicylic acid, combinations excl. psycholeptics
Basiliximab
BCG vaccine
Beclometasone
Beclometasone and antibiotics
Cefazolin
Cefdinir
Cyclobenzaprine
Cyclopentolate
Diosmin
Diosmin, combinations
Dioxydine*
Diphenhydramine
Diphtheria antitoxin
Diphtheria toxoid
```

Part of *'file_regex'*

```
^(\w+)\*$
[A-Za-z].+combinations
[Dd]i((ph)|(f)).+$
```

I'm using

```
Windows 7 (x86)
Git For Windows 2.34.1.1 (git-bash.exe)
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (i686-pc-msys)
sed (GNU sed) 4.8
```

Comment: Can you format your code better?

Comment: Check your scripts with shellcheck and implement the suggested fixes.

Comment: I don't understand what substituion you are looking for. Give a concrete example for your `file_with_set_of_regexes`, one example input-file, and the output you want to achieve.

Comment: use `while read -r regex; do ...; done <./file_regex` otherwise lines can be split unexpected

Comment: use `set -x` to see what is actually executed. You will almost certainly find that the sed command is not what you wanted

Comment: `$(...)` should be used in preference to backticks. Note that nothing expands inside single-quotes.

Comment: jhnc, 'while read' loop doesn't work in my case, but [link](https://www.shellcheck.net/) tells me that everything is fine:  ->> No issues detected! <<-

Comment: You have to show us the contents of your file of regexps and tell us which regexp variant you use (BRE or ERE or PCRE) if you want us to help you write a script that uses them since every tool supports different regexp variants with different options, delimiters, backreference support or not, extensions, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. I use ERE variant. I just want to use variable substitution in the sed editor. Never thought it would be so difficult

Answer (score 0):

Split it up into two steps, using `grep` to filter the lines, since it has an option to read regular expressions from a file instead of command line arguments:

```bash
grep -Ef file_with_set_of_regexes file_with_data_to_check \
  | sed 's/$/some string/' > file_with_processed_data
```

Comment: See [In Bash, how do I add a string after each line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2869669/9952196) for alternatives to sed for appending text to each line; something there might work better for you.

Comment: (I like the `lam` (if you have it) and `awk` approaches. Not everything needs a regular expression.)

Comment: Hi Shawn! Thank you very much for edition of my question and foregive my english please!
You suggest a great solution, but what if I need to use one more substitution, say, instead of 'some string'. In this particular question I try to use variables in conjunction with 'bash substitution' and I'm little bit upset that it doesn't work very good in the sed editor. More close to my question is - [link](http://example.com)https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/207963-solved-sed-error-multiple-number-options-command.html) Here variables and substitutions are used to work with sed.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#.*#/&/ba#' regexFile | sed -f - -e 'b;:a;s/$/some string/' file
```

Convert the file of regexps into a sed script and apply it to the source file.

In this scenario, each regexp is sent to a named goto, which then appends a string to the end of the line.

Otherwise, the line is left as is.

Comment: Thanks, Potong, but in your version the substitution of the string "some string" is not carried out